# On Javascript, why is a function that is not bound using bind() still binds to the object?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, the first function is not bound to `obj`, but the second function is, so `f()` returns `fifi` and `g()` returns `Mark Twain` as expected.  But the 3rd attempt, it is by `(obj.getCallBack)` first, which is now a function, and then it is invoked, essentially it should be the same as the `f` case.  But they do print out `Mark Twain` instead.  Why are they not bound to `obj` using `bind()` but still got executed with `this` pointing to `obj`?

(the 4th attempt is just a usual invocation of a method, and `this` should bind to the object on which the method is invoked on).

(tested on the current Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9)

```
window.name = "fifi";

var obj = {
    name: "Mark Twain",
    getCallBack: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

var f = obj.getCallBack;
var g = f.bind(obj);

console.log(f);
console.log(f());

console.log(g);
console.log(g());

console.log((obj.getCallBack)());
console.log(obj.getCallBack());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting that if a function is called as a property of some object, that object will be the `this` for the call. So:

```
obj.getCallBack() //The function referenced by `obj.getCallBack`
                    //is called as a property of `obj`, so obj will be `this`
                    //for the call

f()    //The function referenced by f, is not called as a property of some object so
         //`this` will depend on strict mode.
```

After these basic rules, the bound function will be invoked, which can be thought of as a proxy function (any shim does this) that uses `.call/.apply` to explicitly set the context for the target function. So the `this` value for the proxy function doesn't matter, but behind the scenes it was set by the basic rules.

Edit:

`(obj.getCallBack)` [does not return the function as value, because getValue is not called.](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.6). So it is exactly the same as `obj.getCallback` and the first post applies.

So you can do this and not get an error:

```
(obj.getCallback) = 5;
```

As opposed to:

```
(function(){}) = 5; //invalid assignment
```

Comment: But I thought when `(obj.getCallBack)` is used, it merely denotes a function, without ever evaluating what `this` is.  That is, it is just static text definition of what the function is.  So what I mean is, `this` is taken as the text, but NOT evaluated.  And then when invoked using `()`, it is invoked as a function.  Unless you are saying that `this` is evaluated, then that should mean `this.name` is also evaluated, so it should already be `Mark Twain` already.

Comment: @動靜能量 `(obj.fn)()` and `obj.fn()` are the same thing. `(obj.fn)()` -> `obj.fn()` -> function is called a as property of `obj.`

Comment: it is funny that `console.log(f === (obj.getCallBack));` will print out true, while invoking them gives different results.  maybe the comparison doesn't take the binding into consideration

Comment: @動靜能量 Yes, they reference the same function. `this` is resolved for each and every *call* separately, regardless of how or where the function is defined. The value of `this` *only* depends on *how* the function is invoked. Your `.bind` does not affect `f` or `obj.getCallBack` at all.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Esailija's answer, the desired effect actually should be:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Mark Twain",
    getCallBack: function() {
        return function() { return this.name; };
    }
}

var f = obj.getCallBack();
var g = f.bind(obj);

console.log(f);
console.log(f());

console.log(g);
console.log(g());

console.log((obj.getCallBack())());
console.log(obj.getCallBack()());

console.log(obj.getCallBack().bind(obj)());
```

Then in this case, the third attempt will give `fifi`, and so will the 4th attempt.  To get the name inside `obj`, the fifth attempt binds it and invoke it and will get `Mark Twain`.

But the method that returns the callBack function should bind it, so let's change the code to:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Mark Twain",
    getCallBack: function() {
        return (function() { return this.name;}).bind(this);  // <-- note here
    }
}
```

and now all attempts, even `f()`, will return `Mark Twain`.